# How do i set up VScode so i can click on file line in debug outputs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I previously had my VSCode set up for my python project so when a test failed, I could click on a line in the trace debug output and the file would automatically open in my editor window at the given line. However that is no longer happening for me.

Does anyone know what factors affect this feature's configuration?

My environment:

- Windows 10
- Terminal type: Powershell
- Programming language: Python

Example:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_single_email_sending (common.tests.email_Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\git repos\lang\common\tests.py", line 240, in test_single_email_sending
    from_addr=from_addr,
  File "D:\git repos\lang\common\email.py", line 29, in send_single_email
    for attc in attachment_file_objs:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s
```

Comment: read up on problem matchers in tasks

Comment: @rioV8 - Yes, I can see this is the right approach. There must be a regex defined in a problemMatcher file that can't handle spaces in the pathname. My root directory "git repos" is new and I now notice the clickable link appears for files in different directories. Any idea where I can find and update the problemMatcher config file for terminal?

Comment: in the test-sicebar you can also go to the file with the failing test, hover the mouse over the line and you see a few extra buttons. I did a quick search in the `ms-python,*` extension but could not find a place that was looking for unittest fails. It is not a problem matcher because it is in the `Python Test Log` OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

I use the unittest to click "`Debug Test`" and get the following in the "`Python Test Log`" of "`OUTPUT`". When I click "Ctrl" and click "d:...\pythonVScode\test05\a\b\ test_unittest.py", the edit bar automatically jumps to the error line "w3":

[image]

If this is not what you want, please describe in detail and let me know.